# bash copy with white spaces problems

Tags: bash

i'm trying to create a backup script and can't get inte to handle whitespaces in the right way when i try to copy. I have searched everywhere but can't find a solution that works. The problem is when it tries to to copy the file "test whitespaces" it interprets it as to different files. My code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/backup

number_of_files=$(ls |wc -l)


while [ $number_of_files -gt 9 ] 
do
ls -t | tail -n -1 | xargs rm -rf 
number_of_files=$(( $number_of_files -1 ))
done
mkdir temp
cd  temp
number_of_home=$( ls / | grep home | wc -l) 
i=1

while [ $i -lt $number_of_home ]
do 
    user=$(ls -l $(find /home$i -iname .backuprc) | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
    mkdir $user

    for file in "$(find /home$i -iname .backuprc -exec cat  {} \;  );" 
    do
             cp "$file" /var/backup/temp/$user;
    done
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done
cd /var/backup
tar -czf $( date '+%k.%M.%S_%m%d%y').tar temp
rm  -r /var/backup/temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in "$(find /home$i -iname .backuprc -exec cat  {} \;);" 
do
     cp "$file" /var/backup/temp/$user;
done
```

Switch this to:

```
find /home$i -iname .backuprc -exec cat {} \; | while read file; do
    cp "$file" /var/backup/temp/$user;
done
```

Or:

```
find /home$i -iname .backuprc -exec cat {} \; | xargs -d '\n' cp -t /var/backup/temp/$user
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `IFS=$'\n'` to the beginning of your script.  This will cause spaces not to be considered a Field Separator.

Comment: That's a rather aggressive option. There's high potential for breaking other lines.

Comment: It is a script so it only affects the script.  If there are other lines in the script that need another value, set it again.